# Accessing DOMelements generated by Shopify BuyButton.js UI Client

Tags: javascript, sdk, shopify, buybutton.js

I'm building a website where I want to run a secondary function when the "Add to Cart" button is clicked.

For some reason when I try using any sort of event listener or getElementsbyTagName to access the button created by the BuyButton script, it always returns as undefined and gives me this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')**

Here's my code:

```
   <script src="http://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/1.0.0/buybutton.js" ></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="shopifyDiv"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
          domain: 'shopify.myshopify.com',
          storefrontAccessToken: '(myTokenHere)',
        });

        var ui = ShopifyBuy.UI.init(client);

        
        ui.createComponent('product', {
        id: (myIdHere),
        node: document.getElementById('shopifyDiv'),
        options: {
            product:{
              width: '350px',
              contents:{
                img: false,
                button: true,
                title: false
              },
              text: {
          button: 'Add to cart'
        },
            },
          cart:{
            startOpen: false
          },

        }
      
      });


    /*]]>*/
    </script>



  <script type="module">

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].innerHTML = 'hello world';

       </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I removed the Shopify specific accessToken & domain name for security purposes.

Any help in understanding why these DOM Elements that are being created by the Shopify script are inaccessible would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify BuyButton generates an iframe inside your element.

This means two things:

- You need to wait for the element to be present in the DOM (since this makes async request, you can't access it on DOM ready)
- You need to get the content of the iframe in order to get the button

So you need to chain a `.then` to your component creation method, like so:

```
ui.createComponent('product', {
  // your original code
}).then((res) => {
  const iframe = document.querySelector('#shopifyDiv iframe').contentDocument;
  iframe.querySelector('button').innerHTML = 'hello world';
});
```

An target the iframe content inside of there and do your logic afterwards.

And that's pretty much all you have to do.

Comment: wow thank you that's super helpful! is there a way to pass something like a setAttribute Id into that ``.then`` that would make it able to be seen by another script that's linked later in the <body>?